# backend.set_image_data_format('th') returning unexpected errors

Tags: keras, backend

I am trying to implement some code, and when I run my notebook, I have returned the following errors:

[image: image data format TensorFlow backend error]

[image: image data format TensorFlow backend error #2]

I am not too sure what I am doing wrong and why I am receiving this error. I have also tried to use set_image_dim_ordering but not luck.

Comment: You can even see in the traceback what are the valid values. "th" is not one of them since years.

Comment: Oh yeah, silly me. I have found a workaround now. Thanks for the pointer.